# Use of he, him and it in a conversation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, interpersonal-relations

I don't fully understand the relationship between the following conversations. Suppose, two men are fighting, and there are three commentators. At this point man 2 intends to attack man 1.

> **Commentator 1:** someone strikes, "Wait! Man 1"
>
> **Commentator 2:** "He may have suckered him there."
>
> **Commentator 2:** "blocked it." *someone strikes again*
>
> **Commentator 2:**
>
> **Commentator 3:** "woaw!"
>
> **Commantary3:** "That's it! That's it!"

*Then man 2 proceeds to destroy man 1*

Suppose we are tracking the actions of the fighters through commentary alone. My questions are:

- On commentator 2's statement "He may have suckered him there.", who is he? Who is him?
- On commentary1's statement "blocked it.", Who did the blocking? Man1 or man2?

Comment: Where exactly did this come from? Without any additional context it's impossible to say. It seems very strange to me that any commentator would not know who was throwing a punch. If you've made this all up, then it's contrived to be deliberately ambiguous. Without the right context (or syntax), pronouns are easily ambiguous.

Comment: @Jason Bassford It came from here. Around 7 min and 35 sec of part 5.
http://watchwrestlingbid.com/wrestling/watch-njpw-g1-climax-27-day-19-81217/
I am blind so I rely on commentary. But english is not my first language so I may not understand it correctly. Also I edited my question to give more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying your question.

I realize now that the text you have in asterisks is not spoken dialogue but description.

I watched the [video clip](http://watchwrestlingbid.com/wrestling/watch-njpw-g1-climax-27-day-19-81217/) (part 5) in question a couple of times. It's very confusing. Of all the things I can think of to try to follow purely with commentary, wrestling seems like one of the worst.

At seven minutes and thirty seconds, there is a guy standing and attacking (I'll call him Man1 to match your words), and a guy on the ground (I'll call him Man2).

Generally speaking, if somebody is attacking and somebody is defending, then the attacker is the one who has suckered the defender—and the defender is the one trying to block. This may not always be the case, but it's a good assumption. In this case, it was accurate.

To paraphrase the dialogue and insert the actual names:

> "Wait! Man1"
>   "Man1 may have suckered Man2 there."
>   "Man2 blocked it."

The use of *it* later on seems to simply be an excited utterance on the part of a commentator. It's either referring to a kick specifically, or just the general situation that has Man1 beating Man2.

However, the only way I could get any of this for sure was by matching the commentary to visual cues. If I only had the commentary to go by, I could assume certain things (as I mentioned in terms of attacking and defending and who's likely doing what), but the language and pronouns used would make it difficult.